# LaTeX \url{} in italics

Tags: url, latex

Is there a simple way of getting a LaTeX url to display in italics, i.e. `emph{\url{http://www.stackoverflow.com}}`? FYI I am also using \urlstyle{same} right before, which keeps the style looking like the document default style, but I don't want to set my document default to italics.

Comment: Is your `\url{}` from the hyperref package?

Comment: No, from package url \usepackage{url}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily set urls to italic text by setting the UrlFont in the document, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\def\UrlFont{\em}
\url{http://www.address.com}

\end{document}
```

The url should appear in italics.

Comment: Does not seem to work... Regardless of whether I place it before or after \begin{document}

Comment: Are you using the url package? What error message are you getting?

Comment: OK, I've edited my example above. It's a minimal latex file that compiles using vanilla latex, and should put all your urls into italics. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try setting `\UrlFont` to `\itshape`, i.e.

```
\renewcommand\UrlFont\itshape
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,

```
\textit{\url{etcetcetc.com}}
```

using

```
\usepackage{url}
```